# HOW TO fire two insert command in sqlserver with Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
if (dpsessional.SelectedItem.Text.ToString().Equals("1"))
{

if (lengthofbatch == 1)
              {

                 com = new SqlCommand("insert into Attendence_Stu_Main(st_id,st_rollno,st_name,branch_name,sem_no,batch_year,batch_name,scode,sess_no,attendence,total) values (@Stid,@Strollno,@Stname,@Stbranch,@Ssemno,@Syear,@Sbatch,@Scode,@Ssessno,@Satt,@Stotal)", con);
              }
              else
              {
                  if (lbsubjecttype.Text.Equals("L"))

                  {
                      com = new SqlCommand("insert into Attendence_Stu_Main(st_id,st_rollno,st_name,branch_name,sem_no,batch_year,batch_name,scode,sess_no,attendence,total) values (@Stid,@Strollno,@Stname,@Stbranch,@Ssemno,@Syear,firstchar,@Scode,@Ssessno,00,00)", con);


                      com = new SqlCommand("insert into
```

Attendence_Stu_MainL1(st_id,st_rollno,st_name,branch_name,sem_no,batch_year,batch_name,scod
e,sess_no,attendence,total) values

(@Stid,@Strollno,@Stname,@Stbranch,@Ssemno,@Syear,@Sbatch,@Scode,@Ssessno,@Satt,@Stotal)",

con);
                      }
                      else

```
                  {
```

com = new SqlCommand("insert into

Attendence_Stu_MainL1(st_id,st_rollno,st_name,branch_name,sem_no,batch_year,batch_name,scod

e,sess_no,attendence,total) values

(@Stid,@Strollno,@Stname,@Stbranch,@Ssemno,@Syear,@Sbatch,@Scode,@Ssessno,@Satt,@Stotal)",

con);

```
                  }

                }
          }

               com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stid", g1.Cells[0].Text);
```

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Strollno", g1.Cells[1].Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stname", g1.Cells[2].Text);

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stbranch", g1.Cells[3].Text);

```
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ssemno", g1.Cells[4].Text);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Syear", g1.Cells[5].Text);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sbatch", label1);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Scode", label2);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ssessno", label3);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Satt", textbox);

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stotal", textbox1);





            com.ExecuteNonQuery();


            con.Close();
        }

        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

            Label5.Text = ex.Message;

            Label5.Visible = true;
        }




    }

}
```

...........................................................................................

com = new SqlCommand("insert into 
Attendence_Stu_Main(st_id,st_rollno,st_name,branch_name,sem_no,batch_year,batch_name,scode,
sess_no,attendence,total) values 
(@Stid,@Strollno,@Stname,@Stbranch,@Ssemno,@Syear,firstchar,@Scode,@Ssessno,00,00)", con);

com = new SqlCommand("insert into

Attendence_Stu_MainL1(st_id,st_rollno,st_name,branch_name,sem_no,batch_year,batch_name,scod

e,sess_no,attendence,total) values

(@Stid,@Strollno,@Stname,@Stbranch,@Ssemno,@Syear,@Sbatch,@Scode,@Ssessno,@Satt,@Stotal)",

con);

from 2 of the insert command only one is fired and other is not fired..I have tried using

debugging,it show's clear traversing but not able to store in table

Comment: Please edit your posting so that it is readable.

Comment: Tried to make sense from the mess above. I have given up, please before posting try to reformat the code to be readable.

Comment: @Steve - I, too, simply gave up.  Such a mess...

Answer (score 4):

Even though this is the most unreadable question in humanity, I am going to try and answer this. If you can make your question readable and concise, and let us know what you are expecting, then do it.

You are constantly overwriting your commands.

```
com = new SqlCommand("insert into Attendence_Stu_Main(st_id,st_rollno,st_name,branch_name,sem_no,batch_year,batch_name,scode,sess_no,attendence,total) values (@Stid,@Strollno,@Stname,@Stbranch,@Ssemno,@Syear,firstchar,@Scode,@Ssessno,00,00)", con);
```

and then, without actually *submitting* this change to the database, you are overwriting it:

```
com = new SqlCommand("insert into Attendence_Stu_MainL1(st_id,st_rollno,st_name,branch_name,sem_no,batch_year,batch_name,scode,sess_no,attendence,total) values (@Stid,@Strollno,@Stname,@Stbranch,@Ssemno,@Syear,@Sbatch,@Scode,@Ssessno,@Satt,@Stotal)",
```

I would make them two different `SqlCommand` instances.

Just as a side note, the database table & column naming scheme you've got going on, not so pretty.

Comment: +1 for using night vision to read the code :)

Comment: I don't know if you are right or not. +1 just because you have tried to understand

Comment: @Steve:Yeas,i got it...But for My database here, i am working on Attendence system and for my college there are 3 phases ,so i have make 3 diff. table with same attribute for generating Excel reports at last,so it is much convient for JOINS...Thanks for helping,,and your suggestion..